# How much can showering affect body temperature?

Tags: body-temperature

Because of the COVID-19 outbreak, I have been monitoring my temperature to help identify if I contract the disease. Today due to a schedule change, I took my temperature orally (under the tongue) shortly after taking a normally-hot shower, and the reading was above my baseline by about 1.5°F (0.8°C). As I have not been feeling any different otherwise, I took another reading after a couple of hours, and it was normal for me.

I suspect that the first reading was high because I had been in a hot environment for several minutes shortly before taking it, but I have not been able to find clear information on the extent to which a hot shower would affect core body temperature. The closest I found was ["Effects of bath water..." by Kawahara et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1572347X05800291) that indicates elevated skin temperature for a bath, but it seems to be focused more on comfort than physiological effects.

After taking a hot shower of typical length (say, 7–8 minutes), what is the typical amount by which a human's body temperature would rise over baseline?

Comment: It sounds like you have the ability to conduct trials using your shower to see.

Comment: @GrahamChiu, it sounds like the OP isn't able to control for confounding factors, so any trials will be of limited value.

Comment: @Mark Additionally, the sample size would be quite low, both in population and number of trials each.

Comment: the question is about the OP's body temperature response.  We can't measure other people's responses to their shower temperature.  They have to do this. (Geez, trying to be gender neutral is hard )

Comment: @GrahamChiu Rephrasing, though the fair suggestion could have been made with less snark and more clarity.

Comment: You're asking for personal medical advice which is off topic.

Comment: Body weight, skin surface area, water temperature, water flow, air temperature, age, gender, health status, medications -- those are the variables I can think of offhand that would have to be known to even begin to answer this question.